# Jquery Dropdown Groups

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu, multiple-select

I have a problem with select (Dropdown) box...

the problem is i have a set of dropdowns and every dropdown having a set of dropdowns ..

While change a dropdown then all child dropdowns are selected by changed values

---

please help me

The following code having dropdown boxes

When a parent dropdown change then all child dropdowns will selected by that changed value

```
     <table>
      <tr>
         <th>Parent DropDown</th>
        <th colspan="3">Child Dropdowns</th>
      </tr>
 <tr>
<td>
<select name="class_1" id="class_1">
<option value="First">First</option>
<option value="Second">Second</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<select name="subClass_1" class="select_1">
<option value="First">First</option>
<option value="Second">Second</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<select name="subClass_2" class="select_1">
<option value="First">First</option>
<option value="Second">Second</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<select name="subClass_3" class="select_1">
<option value="First">First</option>
<option value="Second">Second</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<select name="class_2" id="class_2">
<option value="First">First</option>
<option value="Second">Second</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<select name="subClass_1" class="select_2">
<option value="First">First</option>
<option value="Second">Second</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<select name="subClass_2" class="select_2">
<option value="First">First</option>
<option value="Second">Second</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<select name="subClass_3" class="select_2">
<option value="First">First</option>
<option value="Second">Second</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<select name="class_3" id="class_3">
<option value="First">First</option>
<option value="Second">Second</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<select name="subClass_1" class="select_3">
<option value="First">First</option>
<option value="Second">Second</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<select name="subClass_2" class="select_3">
<option value="First">First</option>
<option value="Second">Second</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<select name="subClass_3" class="select_3">
<option value="First">First</option>
<option value="Second">Second</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: _"please help me"_ - You need to help us to help you. Explain more clearly what the desired behaviour is, and **show your code.**

Comment: @nnnnnn I am just updated my question now by placing the html code....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand it's parent child relationship between dropdowns. when the value of parent dropdown is changed, accrodingly the values in child dropdown should also get changed.

These scenario is often found in Country,State,City selection.

If this is the case then you need to handle onchange event for dropdown.

```
$(element).change(function(){
    //coding for the same..................
});
```